# Why Laravel "Console::info()" doesn't works, error: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Console' not found in MY CONTROLLER"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am absolutly new in **PHP** and in **Laravel**.

I am working on a Laravel **controller** class and I have put these 2 line

Console::info('username: ' + $userName);
   Console::info('password ' + $pswd);

to log what happens in the code.

So my entire controller class is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class LoginBetriviusController extends Controller
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //metodo richiamato al caricamento della web application - carica la pagina principale
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function index(){
        return view('login');       
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //TODO _ implementare chiamata per la LOGIN
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function doLogin(){

        $userName = Input::get('username');
        $pswd = Input::get('password');

        Console::info('username: ' + $userName);
        Console::info('password ' + $pswd);

        return view('dashboard-hotel');
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //FINE --- implementare chiamata per la LOGIN
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

the prolem is that when enter in this method I am obtaining the following error message when try to execute the first **Console::info** method:

```
[Mon Jan 23 17:48:46 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Console' not found in C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius
\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\app\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController.php on line 34
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You'll have to namespace it or add a \ in front of it, depending on which Console class you're trying to use. Console is not a native Laravel class that I can see. Also, plus signs are not used for concatenation.

Comment: @aynber what have I to change? I am absolutly new in PHP...

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're trying to do (output the information somewhere so you can view it), use Alexey's answer.

Comment: @aynber in this way I have no error message but is not displayed into the bash console, why?

Comment: Because it's a PHP function, not javascript. Anything written with the Log class gets written to `/storage/logs/` on the server.

Comment: And how can I print it on the bash console instead of a log file?

Comment: `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#logging) facade.

Namespace it with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;` and simply call `Log::info('My log data');`

Although I strongly discourage storing password data and especially in plain text!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#logging) facade:

```
\Log::info('username: '.$userName);
\Log::info('password '.$pswd);
```

Comment: Sending plain plain text passwords to log? Mmm... delicious.

Comment: Doing in this way I obtain no error but the messages are not displayed into the shell. Why?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, good for you. What if this answer read (i.e. copy & paste) innocent children?

Comment: @AndreaNobili check `storage/logs/laravel.log` file permissions.